# How to set the background of the application to be animated (Live wallpaper?)

Tags: android, background, live-wallpaper

I have a simple application for Android and would like to set the background to be animated. How can I do this?

1. I have to create a live wallpaper, install it on phone and then use in my application? If so, how do I use it in my application?
2. Is it possible to set within my project a live wallpaper or any other type of animated background? That is, without requiring a separate application? If so, how do I do that?

In short, I would like the background of my application to animated, regardless of how it is done (live wallpaper, gif, video, whatever ...)

Comment: Have you found the answer to this question?

Comment: What kind of animation did you have in mind? Video? xml? Theres many ways to do that so please be more specific.

Comment: Never mind it guys, I moved to another project. Thanks for the help and sorry for the delay in responding.